# jQuery trigger pinch gesture on iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, mobile-safari

So I am developing a WEB app for iPad and have a problem with device rotation. Depending on the initial orientation when the orientation changes the page appears zoomed in. Now the user can simply pinch to return to an acceptable experience, but that is not nearly good enough. So here is what I want to do. I want to trigger a 'pinch' event with javascript that would behave the same as a real user zoom out.

However I am not sure this is even possible, as I have had zero success triggering touchmove events. Plus I would have to trigger 2 touchmove events moving toward each other.

```
 $('body').trigger('touchmove' ... how would I pass in X and Y?
```

Now I saw this example in jQuery's documentation:

```
var event = jQuery.Event("logged");
event.user = "foo";
event.pass = "bar";
$("body").trigger(event);
```

which makes me think passing data into a triggered event object is possible, but how would a full pinch be triggered?

Answer (score 1):

I may be misunderstanding your question, but are you not simply trying to stop the page from needing to be pinched?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

This will tell the device that you have designed the page for iPad and that it does not require scaling!

Comment: not an option. For the page to display correctly, it has to have a custom width. `width=1024, initial-scale=default`